# Create exe shortcut using Setup Wizard Visual studio

Tags: c#, installation, exe, windows-forms-designer, setup-wizard

I created a Windows Forms application and added a Setup Wizard.
I want the installer to create a SHORTCUT of my exe on the desktop but not a COPY of it because the exe uses resources from the folder its in.
I added a shortcut using this article: http://gaurangpatel.net/creating-application-shortcut-in-programs-for-windows-installer-project.
but it created a copy of the exe instead of a shortcut.
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In File system view, go to Application folder and right click your main output. Select *Create shortcut to...* and drag and drop that shortcut to the User's desktop directory.

[image: screenshot]